# Error in uploadng image using alamofire

Tags: ios, arrays, alamofire

I am trying to upload image using Alamofire. But application is crashing when I try to make the app rquest with following message:

> -[**NSCFNumber dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000013
>   2018-02-20 00:19:58.167574+0530 ProSales[63550:5801521] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000013'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104ea812b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000103feff41 objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104f29024 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
>       3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104e2af78 ___forwarding_** + 1432
>       4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104e2a958 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
>       5   ProSales                            0x0000000103125b03 _T08ProSales17NetworkOperationsC11uploadImageySS3url_s10DictionaryVySSyXlG5paramSo7UIImageC5imageyAA6ResultOc17completionHandlertFZy9Alamofire17MultipartFormDataCcfU_ + 1011
>       6   ProSales                            0x0000000103125de3 _T08ProSales17NetworkOperationsC11uploadImageySS3url_s10DictionaryVySSyXlG5paramSo7UIImageC5imageyAA6ResultOc17completionHandlertFZy9Alamofire17MultipartFormDataCcfU_TA + 99
>       7   Alamofire                           0x0000000103688c74 _T09Alamofire14SessionManagerC6uploadyyAA17MultipartFormDataCc09multipartfG0_s6UInt64V14usingThresholdAA21URLRequestConvertible_p4withyAC0efG14EncodingResultOcSg18encodingCompletiontFyycfU_ + 212
>       8   Alamofire                           0x000000010368c59c _T09Alamofire14SessionManagerC6uploadyyAA17MultipartFormDataCc09multipartfG0_s6UInt64V14usingThresholdAA21URLRequestConvertible_p4withyAC0efG14EncodingResultOcSg18encodingCompletiontFyycfU_TA + 156
>       9   Alamofire                           0x0000000103611269 _T0Ix_IyB_TR + 41
>       10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109d1b2f7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
>       11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109d1c33d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
>       12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109d283a2 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1444
>       13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109d27da0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
>       14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010a1e35a2 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
>       15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010a1e307d start_wqthread + 13
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Code for uploading the image:

```
class func uploadImage(url:String, param:[String:AnyObject], image:UIImage, completionHandler: @escaping CompletionHandlerType){
    let imageData: Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:{ multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "image",fileName: "image.png", mimeType: "image/png")
        for (key, value) in param {
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
        }
    },
         to:url,
         method:.put,
         headers:getHeader(),
         encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                    completionHandler(.Success(true))
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
    })
}
```

I am adding the parameter as following:

```
    if !name.isEmpty{
        parameters["name"] = name as AnyObject
    }
    if !email.isEmpty{
        parameters["email"] = email as AnyObject
    }
    if !password.isEmpty{
        parameters["password"] = password as AnyObject
    }
    if !mobile.isEmpty{
        parameters["mobile"] = mobile as AnyObject
    }
```

Comment: I think you getting response in true or false that is 1 or 0 that is your problem

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here

```
  multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
    }
```

as the

```
  param:[String:AnyObject]
```

contains a value of type NSNumber ,  so you can try convert NSnumber to string

```
   let myString = value.stringValue
   let myData = myString.data(using: .utf8)
```

Edit

```
  var parameters:[String:String]?
```

///

```
  if !name.isEmpty{
        parameters["name"] = name as String
    }
    if !email.isEmpty{
        parameters["email"] = email as String
    }
    if !password.isEmpty{
        parameters["password"] = password as String
    }
    if !mobile.isEmpty{
        parameters["mobile"] = mobile as String
    }


  parameters["userid"] = String(userid)
```

Comment: one of my parameter is Int, it is userid, how can I pass it this way